# Using CTE to pick columns for main query

Tags: google-bigquery

#### Reproducible Example

This utilizes bigquery public datasets but feel free to substitute similar data structures:

```
with common_columns as (
    select c1.column_name from `bigquery-public-data`.ml_datasets.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c1 where c1.table_name = 'iris'
    INTERSECT DISTINCT
    select c2.column_name from `bigquery-public-data`.ml_datasets.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c2 where c2.table_name = 'iris' and not regexp_contains(c2.column_name,r'sepal')
)

select `species`,`petal_width`,`petal_length` from `bigquery-public-data`.ml_datasets.iris
UNION ALL 
select `species`,`petal_width`,`petal_length` from `bigquery-public-data`.ml_datasets.iris
```

#### Target

What I'm trying to accomplish is using the CTE find the common columns between `c1` and `c2` and then reference those common tables in the union query.

Something like:

```
select (insert column_names from common_columns here) from my_dataset
UNION ALL
select (insert column_names from common_columns here) from my_second_dataset
```

(For the sake of this example, I'm treating `c1` and `c2` as if they were completely different tables, just utilizing the same source table for the sake of an easy example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below example

```
execute immediate( 
  select * from (
    with common_columns as (
      select c1.column_name from `bigquery-public-data`.ml_datasets.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c1 where c1.table_name = 'iris'
      INTERSECT DISTINCT
      select c2.column_name from `bigquery-public-data`.ml_datasets.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c2 where c2.table_name = 'iris' and not regexp_contains(c2.column_name,r'sepal')
    )
    select 'select ' || string_agg(column_name, ', ') || ' from `bigquery-public-data`.ml_datasets.iris'
    from common_columns
  )
)
```

as you can see here - the inner select

```
with common_columns as (
    select c1.column_name from `bigquery-public-data`.ml_datasets.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c1 where c1.table_name = 'iris'
    INTERSECT DISTINCT
    select c2.column_name from `bigquery-public-data`.ml_datasets.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c2 where c2.table_name = 'iris' and not regexp_contains(c2.column_name,r'sepal')
)
select 'select ' || string_agg(column_name, ', ') || ' from `bigquery-public-data`.ml_datasets.iris'
from common_columns
```

outputs dynamically build final select statement - output is

[image]

... and then - `execute immediate` executes it. Obviously you can modify that inner query to build whatever needed in your case - including union all, etc.

Comment: I had no clue `execute immediate` existed. THANKS!